# Finding if two machines can be equivalent

Tags: automata, computational-mathematics

I have this problem:

Consider the following machines **M1** and **M2**. 
**M1** has initial state **A** and the initial state of **M2** is unspecified. 
Can the machines be made equivalent by the correct choice of initial state for **M2**? If so, which state(s) can be chosen?

I'm not sure how to show it? I broke the two machines to partitions, but I don't know if this is the right step to do. I have the tables of states of the FSMs, but I don't think you need it to help me.

**The tables are:**
http://imageshack.us/a/img507/604/26588241.png

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that I couldn’t tell by eye, I’d reduce the machines to minimal equivalent FSMs $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$ and see if the two were identical apart from the missing initial state in $\mathbf{M_2}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott reduce means partition the machine right? for example: M1: {A}{H}{B,G}{C,D}{E}{F} and M2: {A}{E,L}{J,M}{B,N}{G}{C}{E}{H}{D,K} these are the equivalent states in each machine. So M1 and M2 can't be equivalent since M2 has more states? I will add the tables

Comment: No, Mike, there's a whole reduction procedure that's probably in some text or notes you're using.

Comment: The numbers of states are deceptive, because one of the reduced DSMs has two disconnected components; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the minimal DSM $\mathbf{M_2}'$ that you get from $\mathbf{M_2}$, you’ll see that it has two disconnected components, one consisting of the states $\{A\},\{F\}$, and $\{H\}$ and the other of the states $\{E,L\},\{J,M\},\{B,N\},\{D,K\},\{G\}$, and $\{C\}$; let $\mathbf{M_2}''$ be the DSM consisting only of the second component, the one with six states. The minimal DSM $\mathbf{M_1}'$ that you get from $\mathbf{M_1}$ also has six states, $\{E\},\{F\},\{A\},\{B,G\},\{H\}$, and $\{C,D\}$. If you actually sketch the graphs of these DSMs, you’ll notice that they have a lot in common: two loops, and a pair of vertices with transitions going both ways between them. A little more work reveals that they are in fact isomorphic, with the states matching up according to the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{M_1}'&\mathbf{M_2}''\\ \hline
\{A\}&\{B,N\}\\
\{E\}&\{E,L\}\\
\{F\}&\{J,M\}\\
\{B,G\}&\{D,K\}\\
\{C,D\}&\{C\}\\
\{H\}&\{G\}
\end{array}$$

Thus, $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$ are actually equivalent.

Comment: So I was in the right direction? I just didn't see that there are two disconnected components. Thanks Brian.

Comment: @Mike: You’re welcome. As long as the machines are fairly small, I recommend sketching the graphs: most people get a better overall picture of what the machine does from the graph than from the table. In this case that would have made the disconnected components really obvious.

Comment: In my book the definition of reduced is **"a FSM is reduced if it contains no pair of equivalent states"** and we are doing it by partitioning the state set no?

Comment: @Mike: That’s the most common way to do it, yes. (There is another algorithm that works beautifully, but it’s very far from obvious why it works.)

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: So for the answer to the question: if we start at states B or N in M2 both machines are equivalent. right?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that’s right.